# Hosting two websites on same domain

Tags: ajax, tomcat, tomcat7, openshift, appfog

I have two apps named opentripplanner-webapp and opentripplanner-api-webapp. I had successfully deployed them on local tomcat server. Apps has url as `http://localhost:8080/opentripplanner-webapp` and `http://localhost:8080/opentripplanner-api-webapp`. When i deployed apps on appfog , they give me different domains for both apps. The problems is that my apps use ajax request and responses which does not work on cross domains. I am searching for two days to find any solution but didn't find any suitable solution. Kindly guide me.
Thankss

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of options for you:

- Use [JSONP (JSON with Padding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). You would have to write your api so it supports this protocol, but it shouldn't prove too difficult.
- Create both `opentripplanner-webapp` and `opentripplanner-api-webapp` so they support [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). This means that your webapp sends an `Origin` header in the request, and the server responds with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and if they match, the browser accepts the request. This is however [not supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), although most modern browsers do.
- Use a proxy servlet in your opentripplanner-webapp that proxy requests to your API. You can "mount" this servlet at e.g. `/api` in the webapp, and it will forward all requests to opentripplanner-api-webapp internally. So you would send your AJAX requests to `http://webappserver/api` instead of `http://apiserver`. For the browser, this will look like an ordinary same origin request. This will work in all browsers, but might require some more setup.